# In GraphQL how can I discard empty arrays at the query level (not looping after)

Tags: graphql

## Background

I have a menu that I get via GraphQL. It can have nested items inside upto 2 levels.
When I retrieve data I get empty arrays if there are no child links.

## Query

My query looks like this

```
{
  label
  url
  links {
    label
    url
    links {
      label
      url
    }
  }
}
```

So at each level its possible that there's an array of additional links underneath.

## Data

When I check the data it looks something like this

```
{
  "data": {
    "menu": [
      {
        "label": "menu item 1",
        "url": "https://my-site",
        "links": []
      },
      {
        "label": "menu item 2",
        "url": "https://my-site/2",
        "links": []
      },
      {
        "label": "menu item with sub items",
        "url": "https://my-site/got-subs",
        "links": [
          {
            "label": "sub menu item 1",
            "url": "https://my-site/got-subs/1",
            "links": []
          },
          {
            "label": "sub menu item 2",
            "url": "https://my-site/got-subs/2",
            "links": []
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

## Question

How do I remove the empty arrays at the query level so my data looks like this?

```
{
  "data": {
    "menu": [
      {
        "label": "menu item 1",
        "url": "https://my-site",
      },
      {
        "label": "menu item 2",
        "url": "https://my-site/2",
      },
      {
        "label": "menu item with sub items",
        "url": "https://my-site/got-subs",
        "links": [
          {
            "label": "sub menu item 1",
            "url": "https://my-site/got-subs/1",
          },
          {
            "label": "sub menu item 2",
            "url": "https://my-site/got-subs/2",
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry that you are being downvoted. A few people seem to think that if there is no answer to a question, it needs to be downvoted. So the short answer is that this cannot be done. GraphQL is all about the returned JSON being predictable for the client. You could make the return type nullable and your resolver could return `null` if the list is empty. But in most client code this would introduce an extra null check while empty arrays just work (loops will just not run a single iteration). Why do you want to remove it from the response?

Comment: Hi @Herku Thanks for adding a comment. I wanted to remove the empty data to make testing easier since mocking the data requires filling out all the empty arrays and null values, its very strict. But I can just add the extra checks like you said. If you put your comment as an answer I will gladly accept it. thanks.